# an unexpected error in redux while writing actions

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

Here is the code which shouldn't throw any error as per the syntax of redux but it gives an error at line where payload is located.It is

```
Error: 'Unexpected token, expected ;'
// code part 
    const xyz =(response)=>{
      return
      {
        type:GET_ALL_ABC,
        payload:{
          response,
        }
      };
    }
```

Comment: What is `GET_ALL_ABC`?

Comment: Try using parentheses with your return statement.

Comment: IT is one of the action type . THe code is from the codebase of the compnay that i work for and i can't post any code directly so i changed the name .

Comment: @Colin it doesn't help.

Comment: Look at Ravi's answer below, it's what I'm suggesting.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be

```
const xyz =(response)=>{
    return ({
      type:GET_ALL_ABC,
      payload:{
        response,
      }
    });
}
```

with your code the function after compiling will be

```
const xyz = response => {
  return;
  {
      type:GET_ALL_ABC,
      payload:{
        response,
      }
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Automatic_semicolon_insertion; the third rule there is exactly this case.